# "Memory could not be written" error passing an HGLOBAL from VB.Net to a C DLL

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, interop, memory-management

We are using visual studio 2008-My requirement is to allocate some memory, store data into that allocated memory and pass the memory address to a DLL written in C. But when try to pass this memory address to a function in that DLL my application crashes and shows the message "The memory could not be written".

```
''//Memory allocation Code
Dim tmpPtr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Array.GetValue(Array.GetLowerBound(0), Array.GetLowerBound(1))))
''//Copying data to memory
Marshal.StructureToPtr(Array.GetValue(Array.GetLowerBound(0), Array.GetLowerBound(1)), tmpPtr, True)
''//Trying to pass to 'c' dll
StoreStack(tmpPtr)
```

I'm getting the error at the last line.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Wow, your title is way too long.

Comment: Darn it, i was editing, someone beat me to it! oh well, i can still do some work on it...

Comment: Thanks for immediately looking into this... I am not 100% sure about dll functinality is as we do not have it...but guess DLL read data to represent it into picture box. Also want to add few things--We are also using other C DLL's which also copies data to memery and return memory address and we have to use those memory addresses and also want to pass those memory addresses into other C DLL (I am not that much expert but guess might be manage and unmanage memory managemant problem is there) - we are using VS-2008, SP2,XP-Professional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty hard to guess what is going wrong without knowing what managed data structure you are passing to StoreStack and what data structure it expects.  My best guess is that the pointer you are passing to StoreStack is smaller than it expects.

Have you checked the value returned by `Marshal.SizeOf(Array.GetValue(Array.GetLowerBound(0), Array.GetLowerBound(1)))` to make sure that it returns the correct size?

Comment: I also guess there might be problem while allocating memory...may be coz of not getting proper memory size...
Can you please tell, How to get the total memory size allocated by two dimentional array.
--Thanks